# JTabbedPane addTab in wrapper method not working

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtabbedpane

As part of my Diploma in Software Dev we have to create a Java GUI to manage a Soccer League. My group has produced numerous JPanels that in the click-through prototype we put into JTabbedPane. This worked fine up until now where I'm moving them into separate files and into a MVC layout.

I'm using a window class to hold the top level JFrame and menubar and adding in the tabbed panes to that. This works fine in the constructor but when I remove them from the constructor and try to add them from the Bootstrap via the `Window.attachTabbedPanel(String name, JPanel panel)` it doesn't display but querying `tabbedPane.getTabCount()` display an incrementing number of tabs.

Here's a stripped back set of code:
The Bootstrap file:

```
public class Bootstrap {

    private Window mainWindow;

    public Bootstrap() {

        //Window class is our containing JFrame and JMenuBar
        mainWindow = new Window();

        //Load up our view classes
        TestTab tab1 = new TestTab();
        TestTab tab2 = new TestTab();

        //Attach them
        mainWindow.attachTabbedPanel("Tab1", tab1.getScreen());
        mainWindow.attachTabbedPanel("Tab2", tab2.getScreen());

    } // Bootstrap()

    public gui.Window getWindow(){
        return mainWindow;
    }

} // Bootstrap
```

This is called by the Main file:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Bootstrap RunMVC = new Bootstrap();
        gui.Window mainWindow = RunMVC.getWindow();
        mainWindow.run();
    } // main()

} // Main
```

The problem starts here at the Window class, I've added in a `In Constructor` tab to check I haven't stuffed up the tabbedPane but it works fine at that point.

```
public class Window {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JMenuBar menuBarMain;
    private JMenu mnFile;
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private int count;
    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Window() {

        //Build the frame
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1280, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));
        //End Build frame

        TestTab conTab = new TestTab();

        //Add the tabbed pane to hold the top level screens
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);    
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, "name_1");
        tabbedPane.addTab("In Consructor", conTab.getScreen());
        count = 1;
    }

    public void attachTabbedPanel(String name, JPanel panel){
        System.out.println("Window: adding Jpanel name: "+name);
        System.out.println("panel is a: "+panel);
        tabbedPane.addTab(name, panel);
        tabbedPane.updateUI();
        System.out.println("Number of tabs: "+tabbedPane.getTabCount());
        System.out.println("Last Tab .isEnabledAt() "+tabbedPane.isEnabledAt(count++));
        tabbedPane.updateUI();
    }
    /**
     * Launch the window.
     */
    public void run() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Window window = new Window();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And lastly the Panel:

```
public class TestTab {

    private JPanel screen;
    private JLabel lblSeason;
    private JButton btnEdit;
    private JLabel lblRounds;

    public JPanel getScreen() {
        return screen;
    }
    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    public TestTab() {

        screen = new JPanel();
        screen.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[8%,right][10%,left][8%,right][10%,left][grow][50%]", "[][][grow]"));

        lblSeason = new JLabel("Test");
        screen.add(lblSeason, "flowx,cell 0 0");

        btnEdit = new JButton("Edit Test");
        screen.add(btnEdit, "cell 5 0,alignx right");

        lblRounds = new JLabel("More Testing");
        screen.add(lblRounds, "cell 0 1,alignx left");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
public void run() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Window window = new Window();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

You are using new instance of window instead of using created earlier, try to use this code

```
 public void run() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Ah! Of Course it sticks out like a sore thumb now that I look at it.

Comment: Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 0):

`updateUI()` does not do what you think it does.  It should never be called directly - it is called from the superclass constructor to allow the Swing look and feel delegate to initialize itself.

Eliminating the call to `updateUI()` may solve your problem;  or if the tabbed pane is already on screen, you may need to force a repaint/revalidate - the incantation for that is `invalidate(); revalidate(); repaint();`.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I must have missed that bit in the docs. I did see mention of `invalidate(); revalidate(); repaint();` while researching my problem but never in direct reference to `JTabbedPane` are the 3 methods common among the Swing classes?